# java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

my spark job;

```
    val df = spark.sql(s"""""")

    df.write.mode("append").json("hdfs://xxx-nn-ha/user/b_me/df")
```

Error:

```
2019-01-31 19:56:36 INFO  CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend:54 - Driver commanded a shutdown
2019-01-31 19:56:36 INFO  MemoryStore:54 - MemoryStore cleared
2019-01-31 19:56:36 INFO  BlockManager:54 - BlockManager stopped
2019-01-31 19:56:36 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2019-01-31 19:56:36 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 4120.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 5402)
java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.checkOpen(DFSClient.java:808)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.readWithStrategy(DFSInputStream.java:868)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:934)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:735)
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.readBlock(SequenceFile.java:2178)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.next(SequenceFile.java:2585)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileRecordReader.next(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:82)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage12.processNext(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$10$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:614)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:369)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2019-01-31 19:56:36 INFO  Executor:54 - Not reporting error to driver during JVM shutdown.
End of LogType:stdout
```

I got the `java.io.IOException: Filesystem closed` error. Why? I have no hints. Any ideas welcomed. Thanks

*UPDATE*

There is a WARN:

```
2019-02-01 12:01:39 INFO  YarnAllocator:54 - Driver requested a total number of 2007 executor(s).
2019-02-01 12:01:39 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:54 - Requesting 968 new executors because tasks are backlogged (new desired total will be 2007)
2019-02-01 12:01:39 INFO  ExecutorAllocationManager:54 - New executor 25 has registered (new total is 26)
2019-02-01 12:01:39 WARN  ApplicationMaster:87 - Reporter thread fails 1 time(s) in a row.
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidResourceRequestException: Too many containers asked, 1365198
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.RMServerUtils.normalizeAndValidateRequests(RMServerUtils.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ApplicationMasterService.allocate(ApplicationMasterService.java:511)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.service.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBServiceImpl.java:60)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.proto.ApplicationMasterProtocol$ApplicationMasterProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(ApplicationMasterProtocol.java:99)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1714)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2202)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.allocate(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:79)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor36.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.allocate(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.AMRMClientImpl.allocate(AMRMClientImpl.java:277)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnAllocator.allocateResources(YarnAllocator.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:556)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look closer at `DFSClient.checkOpen` code you will see the following:

```
void checkOpen() throws IOException {
    if (!clientRunning) {
      IOException result = new IOException("Filesystem closed");
      throw result;
    }
  }
```

Let's find all accessors of `clientRunning` field.
Only `close` method really changes it. Lets take a look at it:

```
@Override
  public synchronized void close() throws IOException {
    try {
      if(clientRunning) {
        closeAllFilesBeingWritten(false);
        clientRunning = false;
        getLeaseRenewer().closeClient(this);
        // close connections to the namenode
        closeConnectionToNamenode();
      }
    } finally {
      if (provider != null) {
        provider.close();
      }
    }
  }
```

So the main problem in your job is that it tries to write the value, although the FS is already closed.
Make sure you don't close your FS before you do any job. You can also increase the logging level to find the cause.